# How to uninstall taxonomy_menu keeping and converting links in normal menu items?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

After a migration, I've used Taxonomy_menu module to generate taxonomy menu links from some vocs with hundred of terms.

These terms will never change now, so I don't need to keep enabled TM any more, but I need to keep and convert generated menu links in normal menu items.

I'm going to proceed in this way:

1. Disable Taxonomy_menu module
2. Convert all "taxonomy_menu" entries to "menu" in my database ("module" column of "menu_links" table)
3. Uninstall Taxonomy_menu module

Please tell me if the above stuff is enough and **if it is safely**, or there will be bad consequences I can't image now.

Thank you very much for helping me

MXT

Comment: I don't think there is ready-made automata for that. On the other hand, with menu cached, what does it hurt to keep module there? Are you convinced that the benefit of removal will justify the work cost and risk of the process?

Comment: The website is a very complex one, with tons of nodes and terms in menus, and taxonomy_menu is causing performance issues (see: https://drupal.org/node/848018 and https://drupal.org/node/1973920). I've already verified that only disabling TM number of query pass from 2500 per page to 700 per page. So I want to uninstall it at all also because its functionality is no more necessary and I have already 191 modules active in the website. I already know that there aren't automatism, that's why I'm asking if my "manual" actions are safely, thank you

Comment: Consider [Boost](https://drupal.org/project/boost) in such situations - there should be next to no queries during normal reading of a site.

Comment: Boost is unuseful for me because it's a Community site and users are always logged in. I'm also using Redis as cache backend and I've adopted other measeures for high traffic sites.